# Django Python how to calculation time difference given two time strings

Tags: python, django, time, duration

In Django Python, I have 2 timestring for HH:mm, how can I get the duration (difference) ?

Eg:

```
15:30 and 11:00 ---> difference is 04:30
19:28 and 12:25 ---> difference is 07:03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first parse the strings to a `datetime` object with:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

t1 = datetime.strptime(time_str1, '%H:%M')
t2 = datetime.strptime(time_str2, '%H:%M')
```

we then can obtain the absolute difference between the `datetime` objects:

```
dt = abs(t2 - t1)
```

we can now calculate the number of hours and minutes like:

```
t = time(dt.seconds // 3600, (dt.seconds // 60) % 60)
```

and then we can print that number with `strftime`:

```
t.strftime('%H:%M')
```

or as a function:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

def time_diff(time_str1, time_str2):
    t1 = datetime.strptime(time_str1, '%H:%M')
    t2 = datetime.strptime(time_str2, '%H:%M')
    dt = abs(t2 - t1)
    return time(dt.seconds // 3600, (dt.seconds // 60) % 60).strftime('%H:%M')
```

for example:

```
>>> time_diff('15:30', '11:00')
'04:30'
>>> time_diff('19:28', '12:25')
'07:03'
```